# WhyI am Getting 403 Forbidden error for actuator /refresh endpoint on Spring Boot 2 on Cloud Foundry{using Cloud Config Server service}

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

Within my project, I have the following `bootstrap.properties` file:

```
spring.application.name=vault-demo
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Additionally to that, I defined the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The config server is able to access the property but when I update that property in GitHub and POST to `/refresh` I get a `403: Forbidden`. Do I need to make any change in my application or bootstrap.properties?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the solution, I needed to add a security configuration, for example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Additionally, I had to add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

I found this solution within the following GitHub issue:
   https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/950

Comment: Thanks!  Was just barely having the same problem with a POST to the loggers actuator end point and this resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Hey Jason you can also use management.endpoints.web.base-path=/ so that you don't have to use /actuator/refresh to change properties on the fly..this property will set refresh endpoints to /refresh  like in Spring Boot 1.X versions

Comment: Is this solution secure?

Comment: I think it is if we are using authentication using spring security. No?

Comment: I had to csfr().disable();  That was the only change.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that Spring Boot 2 cloud config dont need to be "hooked to /refresh endpoint" after commit (or other events), because the new version always request to remote git Server and compare the last commitId and if is diferrent commitId start to fetch the changes.

If debug and see the log traces, after request http://host:8888/{service}/{profile}/{label_branch} always ask github, and you will notice that if exist changes a "fetch proccess is started " , look at traces like github negotiation:

o.e.jgit.transport.PacketLineOut - git> **want** 4a766a1677....
o.e.jgit.transport.PacketLineOut - git> **have** 93cd4a98b5b3bb7d895...
and finally 
o.e.jgit.transport.PacketLineOut - git> **done**

And after, the download:
o.e.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn - git< ACK 0f8d2413183d5.... common
and so on.

If you look traces and not exist changes (the last commitId is the same, the negotiation and download traces are not shown).

I think that is not a good performance behaviour, so would exist a property that disable it and therefore need a "forced refresh hook behaviour", but i couldn't find it on Spring boot 2.
On the other hand, I like it because you dont need to enable HTTP access to your config server to be notified, so the security configuration is not compromised.

I tried with Greenwich.RELEASE

Hope this helps and clarify this behaviour.