# How to hot-reload properties in Java EE and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, properties

Many in-house solutions come to mind. Like having the properties in a database and poll it every N secs. Then also check the timestamp modification for a .properties file and reload it.

But I was looking in Java EE standards and spring boot docs and I can't seem to find some best way of doing it.

I need my application to read a properties file(or env. variables or DB parameters), then be able to re-read them. What is the best practice being used in production?

A correct answer will at least solve one scenario (Spring Boot or Java EE) and provide a conceptual clue on how to make it work on the other

Comment: Take a look at Spring Cloud Config.

Comment: Personally, I just added/exposed a webservice that could be called instructing the app to reload its properties - so while possibly not a best practice - it worked for me.  It would also minimize resource consumption since it's not doing any sort of continuous polling.

Comment: It's what I had in mind. I just simplified the question. Thanks!

Comment: Posible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations

Comment: This question addresses both spring boot and Java ee in a semi conceptual way

Comment: @BalusC you edited the question as if it's only a spring boot problem, pointing that it's not a java SE problem. I wrote Java EE, please, do not edit the question. It's valid.

Comment: Your question is not answerable by a Java SE user. Spring Boot is not part of Java EE, it's part of Spring.

Comment: I would tend to think that has to do more with JavaSE than SpringBoot and/or JavaEE as the probable solution would be a simple JavaSE helper class.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After further research, [reloading properties must be carefully considered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248486/39998). In Spring, for example, we can reload the 'current' values of properties without much problem. But, special care must be taken when resources were initialized at the context initialization time based on the values that were present in the application.properties file (e.g. Datasources, connection pools, queues, etc.).

**NOTE**:

The abstract classes used for Spring and Java EE are not the best example of clean code. But it is easy to use and it does address these basic initial requirements:

- No usage of external libraries other than Java 8 Classes.
- Only one file to solve the problem (~160 lines for the Java EE version).
- Usage of standard Java Properties UTF-8 encoded file available in the File System.
- Support encrypted properties.

**For Spring Boot**

This code helps with hot-reloading application.properties file without the usage of a Spring Cloud Config server (which may be overkill for some use cases)

This abstract class you may just copy & paste (SO goodies :D ) It's a [code derived from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40288822/39998)

```
// imports from java/spring/lombok
public abstract class ReloadableProperties {
  
  @Autowired
  protected StandardEnvironment environment;
  private long lastModTime = 0L;
  private Path configPath = null;
  private PropertySource<?> appConfigPropertySource = null;

  @PostConstruct
  private void stopIfProblemsCreatingContext() {
    System.out.println("reloading");
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
    Optional<PropertySource<?>> appConfigPsOp =
        StreamSupport.stream(propertySources.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(ps -> ps.getName().matches("^.*applicationConfig.*file:.*$"))
            .findFirst();
    if (!appConfigPsOp.isPresent())  {
      // this will stop context initialization 
      // (i.e. kill the spring boot program before it initializes)
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find property Source as file");
    }
    appConfigPropertySource = appConfigPsOp.get();

    String filename = appConfigPropertySource.getName();
    filename = filename
        .replace("applicationConfig: [file:", "")
        .replaceAll("\\]$", "");

    configPath = Paths.get(filename);

  }

  @Scheduled(fixedRate=2000)
  private void reload() throws IOException {
      System.out.println("reloading...");
      long currentModTs = Files.getLastModifiedTime(configPath).toMillis();
      if (currentModTs > lastModTime) {
        lastModTime = currentModTs;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        @Cleanup InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(configPath);
        properties.load(inputStream);
        environment.getPropertySources()
            .replace(
                appConfigPropertySource.getName(),
                new PropertiesPropertySource(
                    appConfigPropertySource.getName(),
                    properties
                )
            );
        System.out.println("Reloaded.");
        propertiesReloaded();
      }
    }

    protected abstract void propertiesReloaded();
}
```

Then you make a bean class that allows retrieval of property values from applicatoin.properties that uses the abstract class

```
@Component
public class AppProperties extends ReloadableProperties {

    public String dynamicProperty() {
        return environment.getProperty("dynamic.prop");
    }
    public String anotherDynamicProperty() {
        return environment.getProperty("another.dynamic.prop");    
    }
    @Override
    protected void propertiesReloaded() {
        // do something after a change in property values was done
    }
}
```

Make sure to add @EnableScheduling to your @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MainApp  {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

Now you can **auto-wire** the AppProperties Bean wherever you need it. Just make sure to **always** call the methods in it instead of saving its value in a variable. And make sure to re-configure any resource or bean that was initialized with potentially different property values.

For now, I have only tested this with an external-and-default-found `./config/application.properties` file.

**For Java EE**

I made a common Java SE abstract class to do the job.

You may copy & paste this:

```
// imports from java.* and javax.crypto.*
public abstract class ReloadableProperties {

  private volatile Properties properties = null;
  private volatile String propertiesPassword = null;
  private volatile long lastModTimeOfFile = 0L;
  private volatile long lastTimeChecked = 0L;
  private volatile Path propertyFileAddress;

  abstract protected void propertiesUpdated();

  public class DynProp {
    private final String propertyName;
    public DynProp(String propertyName) {
      this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }
    public String val() {
      try {
        return ReloadableProperties.this.getString(propertyName);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  protected void init(Path path) {
    this.propertyFileAddress = path;
    initOrReloadIfNeeded();
  }

  private synchronized void initOrReloadIfNeeded() {
    boolean firstTime = lastModTimeOfFile == 0L;
    long currentTs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((lastTimeChecked + 3000) > currentTs)
      return;

    try {

      File fa = propertyFileAddress.toFile();
      long currModTime = fa.lastModified();
      if (currModTime > lastModTimeOfFile) {
        lastModTimeOfFile = currModTime;
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fa), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(isr);
        properties = prop;
        isr.close();
        File passwordFiles = new File(fa.getAbsolutePath() + ".key");
        if (passwordFiles.exists()) {
          byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(passwordFiles.toPath());
          propertiesPassword = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
          propertiesPassword = propertiesPassword.trim();
          propertiesPassword = propertiesPassword.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
        }
      }

      updateProperties();

      if (!firstTime)
        propertiesUpdated();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void updateProperties() {
    List<DynProp> dynProps = Arrays.asList(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getType().isAssignableFrom(DynProp.class))
        .map(f-> fromField(f))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (DynProp dp :dynProps) {
      if (!properties.containsKey(dp.propertyName)) {
        System.out.println("propertyName: "+ dp.propertyName + " does not exist in property file");
      }
    }

    for (Object key : properties.keySet()) {
      if (!dynProps.stream().anyMatch(dp->dp.propertyName.equals(key.toString()))) {
        System.out.println("property in file is not used in application: "+ key);
      }
    }

  }

  private DynProp fromField(Field f) {
    try {
      return (DynProp) f.get(this);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  protected String getString(String param) throws Exception {
    initOrReloadIfNeeded();
    String value = properties.getProperty(param);
    if (value.startsWith("ENC(")) {
      String cipheredText = value
          .replace("ENC(", "")
          .replaceAll("\\)$", "");
      value =  decrypt(cipheredText, propertiesPassword);
    }
    return value;
  }

  public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key)
      throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 65536, 128);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    byte[] iv = new byte[12];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv); //128 bit auth tag length
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + iv.length + cipherText.length);
    byteBuffer.putInt(iv.length);
    byteBuffer.put(iv);
    byteBuffer.put(cipherText);
    byte[] cipherMessage = byteBuffer.array();
    String cyphertext = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherMessage);
    return cyphertext;
  }
  public static String decrypt(String cypherText, String key)
      throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    byte[] cipherMessage = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cypherText);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipherMessage);
    int ivLength = byteBuffer.getInt();
    if(ivLength < 12 || ivLength >= 16) { // check input parameter
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid iv length");
    }
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
    byteBuffer.get(iv);
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(cipherText);
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 65536, 128);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
    byte[] plainText= cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    String plain = new String(plainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return plain;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
public class AppProperties extends ReloadableProperties {

  public static final AppProperties INSTANCE; static {
    INSTANCE = new AppProperties();
    INSTANCE.init(Paths.get("application.properties"));
  }


  @Override
  protected void propertiesUpdated() {
    // run code every time a property is updated
  }

  public final DynProp wsUrl = new DynProp("ws.url");
  public final DynProp hiddenText = new DynProp("hidden.text");

}
```

In case you want to use encoded properties, you may enclose its value inside ENC() and a password for decryption will be searched for in the same path and name of the property file with an added .key extension. In this example, it will look for the password in the application.properties.key file.

application.properties ->

```
ws.url=http://some webside
hidden.text=ENC(AAAADCzaasd9g61MI4l5sbCXrFNaQfQrgkxygNmFa3UuB9Y+YzRuBGYj+A==)
```

aplication.properties.key ->

```
password aca
```

For the encryption of property values for the Java EE solution, I consulted Patrick Favre-Bulle excellent article on [Symmetric Encryption with AES in Java and Android](https://proandroiddev.com/security-best-practices-symmetric-encryption-with-aes-in-java-7616beaaade9). Then checked the Cipher, block mode and padding in this SO question about [AES/GCM/NoPadding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851612/java-aes-gcm-nopadding-what-is-cipher-getiv-giving-me). And finally, I made the AES bits be derived from a password from @erickson excellent answer in SO about [AES Password Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/39998). Regarding encryption of value properties in Spring, I think they are integrated with [Java Simplified Encryption](http://jasypt.org)

Whether this qualifies as a best practice may be out of scope. This answer shows how to have reloadable properties in Spring Boot and Java EE.

Answer (score 14):

This functionality can be achieved by using a [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server) and a [refresh scope client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope).

**Server**

Server (Spring Boot app) serves the configuration stored, for example, in a Git repository:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
  }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git-repository-url-which-stores-configuration.git
```

configuration file `configuration-client.properties` (in a Git repository):

```
configuration.value=Old
```

**Client**

Client (Spring Boot app) reads configuration from the configuration server by using [@RefreshScope](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/config/annotation/RefreshScope.html) annotation:

```java
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class Foo {

    @Value("${configuration.value}")
    private String value;

    ....
}
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configuration-client
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: configuration-server-url
```

When there is a configuration change in the Git repository:

```
configuration.value=New
```

reload the configuration variable by sending a `POST` request to the `/refresh` endpoint:

```
$ curl -X POST http://client-url/actuator/refresh
```

Now you have the new value `New`.

Additionally `Foo` class can serve the value to the rest of application via `RESTful API` if its changed to `RestController` and has a corresponding endpont.

Comment: What if we dont want to store the configuration on cloud?

Comment: @user666 Where do you want to store it? What are your requirements?

Comment: I want to simply reload the application.properties file each time it changed without restarting the application. Example change in the IP of the Database or any other configuration. The file is stored on the server next to Java Jar

Comment: As instance, if we want to change the actuator password... By the way i was trying to test the refresh endpoint, i am using actuator and spring cloud dependencies, when i call the refresh endpoint from the browser i get: {"timestamp":"2018-12-28T07:01:17.767+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/actuator/refresh"}

Comment: I tried using curl and post it gives forbidden access, maybe because i am using spring security with username and password, how can i achieve this?

Comment: I tried using curl and post it gives forbidden access:
$ curl -X POST -u user:test http://localhost:8081/actuator/refresh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   126    0   126    0     0    448      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   448{"timestamp":"2018-12-28T07:12:09.083+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/actuator/refresh"}

Comment: I fixed refresh issue using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299072/whyi-am-getting-403-forbidden-error-for-actuator-refresh-endpoint-on-spring-boo

Comment: I managed to reload configuration using refresh endpoint however, it does not reload the data source uri for example, it just reload other kind of configuration called in the code programmatically. Any advise on how to reload datasource info?

Comment: @user666 did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @I2obiN i ended up using the old way: org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy

Answer (score 7):

I used @David Hofmann concept and made some changes because of not all was good. 
First of all, in my case I no need auto-reload, I just call the REST controller for updating properties.
The second case @David Hofmann's approach not workable for me with outside files.

Now, this code can work with **application.properties** file from resources(inside the app) and from an outside place. The outside file I put near jar, and I use this  **--spring.config.location=app.properties** argument when the application starts.

```
@Component
public class PropertyReloader { 
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
private StandardEnvironment environment;
private long lastModTime = 0L;
private PropertySource<?> appConfigPropertySource = null;
private Path configPath;
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "app.properties";

@PostConstruct
private void createContext() {
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
    // first of all we check if application started with external file
    String property = "applicationConfig: [file:" + PROPERTY_NAME + "]";
    PropertySource<?> appConfigPsOp = propertySources.get(property);
    configPath = Paths.get(PROPERTY_NAME).toAbsolutePath();
    if (appConfigPsOp == null) {
       // if not we check properties file from resources folder
        property = "class path resource [" + PROPERTY_NAME + "]";
        configPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/" + PROPERTY_NAME).toAbsolutePath();
    }
    appConfigPsOp = propertySources.get(property);
    appConfigPropertySource = appConfigPsOp;
 }
// this method I call into REST cintroller for reloading all properties after change 
//  app.properties file
public void reload() {
    try {
        long currentModTs = Files.getLastModifiedTime(configPath).toMillis();
        if (currentModTs > lastModTime) {
            lastModTime = currentModTs;
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            @Cleanup InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(configPath);
            properties.load(inputStream);
            String property = appConfigPropertySource.getName();
            PropertiesPropertySource updatedProperty = new PropertiesPropertySource(property, properties);
            environment.getPropertySources().replace(property, updatedProperty);
            logger.info("Configs {} were reloaded", property);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Can't reload config file " + e);
    }
}
```

}

I hope that my approach will help somebody

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Boris, Spring Cloud Config is the way to go to avoid patchy solution. To keep the setup minimum, I will suggest the [Embedding the Config Server Approach](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_embedding_the_config_server) with native type (file type). With this approach, the config server is managed locally together with the application.

To support automatic config refresh without calling the actuator endpoint manually, I have created a directory listener to detect file changes and to dispatch refresh scope event.

Proof Of Concept repo ([git](https://github.com/blackjackyau/spring-config-file-based-auto-reloading))

Comment: You need to understand that not everyone wanted to store their properties on an external configuration server

Comment: @NickWills the solution is about managing the properties on a "local/native" config server which is the opposite of the "external"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the properties at realtime and don't want to restart the server then follow the below steps:

1). Application.properties

```
app.name= xyz
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

2). Add below dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

3).Place application.properties in `/target/config` folder. Create the jar in `/target` folder

4).add a classas below ApplcationProperties.java

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class ApplicationProperties {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

5). Write Controller.java and inject ApplcationProperties

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties applcationProperties;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String getString() {
    return applcationProperties.getName();
}
}
```

6).Run the spring boot application

Call `localhost:XXXX/test` from your browser

`Output : xyz`

7). Change the value in application.properties from xyz to abc

8). Using postman send a POST request to localhost:XXXX/actuator/refresh

`response: ["app.name"]`

9). Call localhost:XXXX/find from your browser

`Output : abc`

Answer (score 2):

For spring boot, there's a really good article on this topic [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties), but for multiple property files it doesn't work perfectly.
In my case I had 2 property files, one non sensitive and one containing the passwords. I proceeded with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Extend the spring's PropertySource so that you can add the reloadable version to the environment.

```
public class ReloadablePropertySource extends PropertySource {

    private final PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration;

    public ReloadablePropertySource(String name, String path, ConfigurationListener listener) {
        super(StringUtils.hasText(name) ? name : path);
        try {
            this.propertiesConfiguration = getConfiguration(path, listener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MissingRequiredPropertiesException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String s) {
        return propertiesConfiguration.getProperty(s);
    }

    private PropertiesConfiguration getConfiguration(String path, ConfigurationListener listener) throws ConfigurationException {
        PropertiesConfiguration configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(path);
        FileChangedReloadingStrategy reloadingStrategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
        reloadingStrategy.setRefreshDelay(5000);
        configuration.setReloadingStrategy(reloadingStrategy);
        configuration.addConfigurationListener(listener);
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Now add all of your properties files (now reloadable) inside the spring's env

```
@Configuration
public class ReloadablePropertySourceConfig {

    private final ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @Value("${spring.config.location}")
    private String appConfigPath;

    @Value("${spring.config.additional-location}")
    private String vaultConfigPath;

    public ReloadablePropertySourceConfig(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.config.location")
    public ReloadablePropertySource getAppConfigReloadablePropertySource(){
        ReloadablePropertySource rps = new ReloadablePropertySource("dynamicNonSensitive", appConfigPath, new PropertiesChangeListener());
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
        sources.addFirst(rps);
        return rps;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.config.additional-location")
    public ReloadablePropertySource getVaultReloadablePropertySource(){
        ReloadablePropertySource rps = new ReloadablePropertySource("dynamicVault", vaultConfigPath, new PropertiesChangeListener());
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
        sources.addFirst(rps);
        return rps;
    }

    private static class PropertiesChangeListener implements ConfigurationListener{

        @Override
        public void configurationChanged(ConfigurationEvent event) {
            if (!event.isBeforeUpdate()){
                System.out.println("config refreshed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties)

> We've added the new property source as the first item because we want it to override any existing property with the same key

In our case, we have 2 "reloadable" property sources and both will be looked up first.

Finally create one more class from which we can access the env's properties

```
@Component
public class ConfigProperties {

    private final Environment environment;

    public ConfigProperties(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public String getProperty(String name){
        return environment.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

Now you can autowire `ConfigProperties` and always get the latest property in the files without requiring to restart the application.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigProperties env;

    @GetMapping("/refresh")
    public String test2() {
        log.info("hit");
        String updatedProperty = env.getProperty("test.property");
        String password = env.getProperty("db.password");
        return updatedProperty + "\n" + password;
    }

}
```

where `test.property` is coming from 1st file and `db.password` is coming from another.