# Passing configuration from yaml file to spring boot application without rebuilding it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

How to pass configuration through yaml file to a running spring boot application so that there is no need of rebuilding the application and changes are reflected while the application is runnig?

Comment: You mean changing properties at runtime?

Comment: For that you need to use spring devtools dependencies

Comment: @jdickel yes exactly, do you know that is done in spring boot.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 can we pass configurations using yaml file if we make use of spring devtools dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hot-reload properties in Java EE and Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594764/how-to-hot-reload-properties-in-java-ee-and-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

[How to hot-reload properties in Java EE and Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594764/how-to-hot-reload-properties-in-java-ee-and-spring-boot)

Comment: I guess there is a way to pass yaml conifguration file during time, but how exactly it's done is my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594764/how-to-hot-reload-properties-in-java-ee-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Boot Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/). It allows you to manage your config files centralized and has the ability to push new configurations to the connected applications.

Comment: If I don't want to push the configurations from the external congif-server, instead my configuration file is residing in my project itself so is there any way I can load this file during run time.