# Change value at Runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have the below code .Can I change the ThreadPoolExecutor thread number size at run time ?
I am using spring boot.

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig
{
 @Value(numberOfThreads)
 private String numberOfThreads ; // numberOfThreads is configured app.properties file
@Bean
 public ThreadPoolExecutor executorConfig()
 
 {
        ThreadPoolExecutor e =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        
        return e;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a set method for the property numberOfThread and then provide a way to update it, like a new endpoint. But if your app restarts it will still get the previous value from application.properties.

Other option is to use [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config#overview), but this may or may not be overkill for your case.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648630) goes a bit deeper with some code examples to force a reload.