# Spring application.yaml read complex structure from helm values, which are read from k8s config map

Tags: spring, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a custom map in my application.yml which I would like to update without redeploying each time, it looks like this:

```
devices:
  RDR:
    name: Radar
    networks:
      - local
  VDR:
    name: VRadar
    networks:
      - local
      - external
```

I have a config map, which has the classical key value pair:

```
metadata:
  name: app-env-config
data:
  device-name: vdr
```

And I read it in helm values.yaml

```
env:
  - name: DEV_NAME
    valueFrom: 
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: app-env-config
         key: device-name
```

This works flawlessly when i have a simple value in my application.yaml, however I want to have custom objects, so I would like to pass the whole device object from the configMap to the helm values.yaml to the application.yaml, but so far I haven't found a way to do that, apart from overriding the whole application.yaml which is something I wouldn't want to do, so is there any way, apart from just doing a key value pair, where the value is a json, or whatever, object, which I take as a string from the application.yaml and parse in some way. This would work but is extremely ugly and doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot can [find configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files) in lots of places.  It can read both `application.yml` built into your application's jar file and from the filesystem; you can set an environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONALLOCATION` to specify extra non-default config files.

This means that you can put the YAML you show into a ConfigMap, mount that into a container, and point Spring at it.

Let's take an approach of writing the YAML content as structured content in your Helm values

```yaml
# values-devices.yaml
device:
  name: VDR
  config:
    name: VRadar
    networks:
      - local
      - external
```

You can then write this into a ConfigMap.  We'll generate the YAML here.  An individual ConfigMap item needs to be a string, and we'll use YAML block-scalar syntax to embed YAML.

```yaml
# templates/properties-cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
type: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "app.name" . }}-properties
  labels:
{{ include "app.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  devices.yml: |
    devices:
      {{ .Values.device.name }}:
{{ .Values.device.config | toYaml | indent 8 }}
```

Note the last line: we take the structured `config`, render it `toYaml`, and `indent` every line of it to be in the right place in the structure.  The template line that includes `indent` starts at the first column, it is not itself indented.

Now in your Deployment, you need to declare a container volume from the ConfigMap; mount that into the container filesystem; and set the environment variable.

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        properties-hash: {{ .Values.device | toYaml | sha256sum }}
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: properties
          configMap:
            name: {{ include "app.name" . }}-properties
      containers:
        - name: ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: properties
              mountPath: /etc/properties
          env:
            - name: SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONALLOCATION
              value: file:/etc/properties/devices.yml
```

By default, if you change the `values-devices.yaml` file and re-run `helm upgrade -f values-devices.yaml`, the ConfigMap will update but the Deployment will be unmodified.  The container will see the `/etc/properties/devices.yml` file [change](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically).  It's possible for Spring to reload configuration when this happens ([How to hot-reload properties in Java EE and Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594764/how-to-hot-reload-properties-in-java-ee-and-spring-boot)) but usually you'll need to restart the application.  The `annotations:` in my example embed a hash of the device configuration in the per-Pod metadata, so if the configuration changes, the Pods will be recreated as well.