Spring-boot RabbitMQ rotate credentials
Background-info
I'm using the spring-boot-starter-amqp dependency to connect to RabbitMQ.
In my application.yaml I have:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: <host>
    port: 5672
    username: <username>
    password: <password>

I have a Configuration class where I define a AmqpTemplate like this:
    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpSenderTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

and I have listeners defined like this:

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventListener {
    private final SomeService someService;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.event.someQueue}")
    public void process(SomeEvent event) {
        this.someService.process(event);
    }

We inject the username and password into our containers using a configtree:
spring.config.import: configtree:/etc/apiconfig, ...

The configtree contains the secrets which are dynamic secrets from Hashicorp Vault.
Question/Issue
The RabbitMQ credentials are often rotated for security reasons and re-injected using the configtree.
I don't understand how I can refresh my Amqp connection so that it can handle the credential rotation without having to restart the container.
So, the connection needs to be reset for both receiving (@rabbitlistener) and sending (amqpTemplate).
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
I already looked into @RefreshScope and spring-bus but I can't figure out:

What I should exactly refresh/recreate
How I can automatically detect and trigger the recreation without having to manually call a refresh endpoint.

Any code example is very much appreciated!
Please note that the setup using configtree with Hashicorp cannot be changed.
Also note that the container is running on Kuberenetes.

Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594764/how-to-hot-reload-properties-in-java-ee-and-spring-boot

In summary, you have two straight forward options:

Restart your pods to refresh the secrets.
Using Hashicorp Vault Agent Live Reload.

Restarting the pods is easy and you have the following options:

kubectl delete pods to recreate them
Editing some deployment trivial value to trigger a Rolling Update (e.g., changing the terminationGracePeriodSeconds from 30 to 31).
Use kubectl rollout restart to do a rolling restart on the deployment (For K8s v1.15+)

Using Hashicorp Vault Agent to refresh secrets is well documented in their blog:

Add Spring Actuator dependency: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
Activate Actuator's refresh endpoint: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
Use @RefreshScope annotation in Amqp @Configuration class.
Configure Value Agent in your K8s Deployment/Pod to refresh configuration using Actuator refresh endpoint.

See: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/refresh-secrets-for-kubernetes-applications-with-vault-agent
